# MySQL DISTINCT doesn't work with GROUP BY timestamp

Tags: mysql, distinct

Im trying to get data for google chart. I want to get a sum unique values for every hour of the each day. But `DISTINCT` doesn't work with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") as date,
COUNT(DISTINCT visitor_id) as visitors FROM `visitors`  
WHERE web='example.com' AND created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-02 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-02 23:59:59'
```

The result without `GROUP BY` will be.

```
date                   visitors
---------------------|----------|
2017-11-02 14:00:00  |   2168   |
```

The result with `GROUP BY date` will be

```
date                   visitors
---------------------|----------|
2017-11-02 00:00:00  |    19    | 
2017-11-02 01:00:00  |    16    |
2017-11-02 02:00:00  |    18    |
...                       ...
total will be 2749
```

I want to reach the second result but with right sum of unique values
And the second question is how can I be sure that after few days my unique value won't be assigned to the other date?

Comment: Are you trying to only get the first visit for each visitor?

Comment: I think I have to get only the first distinct value to build a right timestamp chart. But first I want to be sure,that values are unique. Now they aren't

Comment: How would we know what the right sum is? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What are you putting in the group by?

Comment: It's GROUP BY date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to count the right sum with this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") as date,
COUNT(visitor_id) as visitors

FROM (
  SELECT MIN(created_at) AS created_at, visitor_id
  FROM `visitors`

  WHERE web='example.com'
  AND created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-02 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-02 23:59:59'

  GROUP BY visitor_id
) all_visits

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")
```